# Can we say "colloquial context" or "conversational context" instead of "informal context"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-choice

Instead of saying "informal context", can we say either "conversational context" or "colloquial context"?
I thought the words "conversational" and "colloquial" might not be used to desribe a context or a situation since they are generally used to modify language, words or style etc.

For example can we say these sentences:

- ""Gotta" is a word used in conversational contexts."
- ""Gotta" is a word used in colloquial contexts."

Comment: A conversation is not necessarily informal, or colloquial. They all mean different things.

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder if we can use the words I gave to describe contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course:

a conversational context
a colloquial context

can stand-in for and/or explain informality of speech.

But not all informal contexts are oral.

But why not just say conversation and colloquy and not use that word context at all.